# Check if letters in String are in alphabetical order

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm trying to create a function that takes a string and returns true or false, depending on whether the characters are in order or not.

Examples
`isInOrder("abc")` ➞ `true`

`isInOrder("edabit")` ➞ `false`

`isInOrder("123")` ➞ `true`

`isInOrder("xyzz")` ➞ `true`

Here's my attempt which didn't work:

```
public static boolean isInOrder(String str) {
  
    boolean condition = false;


    for(int i = 0 ; i < str.length() ; i++)
    {
        if(str.charAt(i) == 'a')
        {
            if(str.charAT(i+1) == 'b')
            {
                condition = true;
            }
        }
    }
    return condition;
}
```

How do I check if letters in a String are in alphabetical order?

Comment: And what is your problem...?

Comment: Ask yourself: what does the loop body do when `i` is the index for the last character in the string?  Now think about what you need to do to solve that problem.

Comment: Ask yourself: how do you compare two characters to see if one is less than the other?  Now look at what you have written.

Comment: Are a1, 1a, aA, aâ in order?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the String to a char array, sort it, then compare whether the original char array is equal to the sorted one.

```
public static boolean isInOrder(String str) {
    char[] a = str.toCharArray();
    Arrays.sort(a);
    return Arrays.equals(a, str.toCharArray());
}
```

Test Run:

```
bacbdefghi == false
abc123     == false
123abc     == true
abcddefg   == true
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution without sort

```
public static boolean isInOrder(String str) {
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 1; i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) > str.charAt(i + 1)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Test

```
isInOrder("abc")    -> true

isInOrder("edabit") -> false

isInOrder("123")    -> true

isInOrder("xyzz")   -> true
```